# Error reading values after eot

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm not sure why I get this error. All my gems are updated to the latest.

**/bourbon/helpers/font-source-declaration:23: error: error reading values after eot**

When running: (I've gone over it several times, this *should* be correct, but somehow **main.scss** does not compile and put out **main.css**. Or rather, doesn't compile the font-source.)

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('assets/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['css'],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }))
        .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});
```

Is this a version bug, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to update **package.json devDependencies**. For me that was:

```
  "devDependencies": {
"browser-sync": "^2.8.0",
"gulp": "^3.9.0",
"gulp-autoprefixer": "2.3.1",
"gulp-jade": "^1.0.1",
"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"
```

If your sass won't compile, check the devDependencies and update to the most recent. For me, that's the ones over. If you're watching this a lot later, check their websites for the latest version.